# Spring Security : Custom Login without backing bean, using only spring security configurations as j_spring_security_check

Tags: java, spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-security

I'd like to use spring security with JSF2 & richfaces.

If I use the login page generated by spring it works fine.

```xml
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/Admin*" access="isAuthenticated()" />   
    <security:form-login  login-page="/spring_security_login"  login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"  authentication-failure-url="/spring_security_login?login_error"  />
    <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"  invalidate-session="true"/>
    </security:http>
```

Now i want to introduce my custom login.

```xml
    <security:form-login  login-page="/login.xhtml" ....>
```

**login.xhtml:**

```xml
        <h:form id ="select_form" prependId="false">

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="">

            <h:outputText value ="Identifiant :"> </h:outputText>

            <h:inputText name="j_username"  >
                    <rich:placeholder value="Entrez un identifiant..." />
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value ="Mot de passe :"> </h:outputText>

            <h:inputText name="j_password"  >
                    <rich:placeholder value="Entrez un mot de passe..." />
            </h:inputText>

            <h:outputText value =""> </h:outputText>

            <h:commandButton id="btnLoginId" action="j_spring_security_check" value="Login" type="submit" style="float:right;" />

        </h:panelGrid>

    </h:form>
```

The problem is that I want to use j_spring_security_check as describe in security-conf.xml.

But JSF want to redirect to an url who doesn't exist. In fact if i try to configure navigation case in faces-configs.xml to j_spring_security_check , it won't work anyway because j_spring_security_check doesn't give a rendered page, it's more a kind of controller of authentication who does the job for us.

So my question how to configure action login in JSF2 without using a backing bean and just calling the strength of security-conf to make all the work without programing more lines than necessary. Or how to conf the faces-config navigation when using j_spring_security_check? Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATE : it's working fine with hardcoded html without JSF use.**

```xml
  <form name='f' action='/Lyric/j_spring_security_check' method='post'>
   <table>
      <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=""/></td></tr>
      <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='j_password'/></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
   </table>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the URL to which you are submitting the form and also you need to change the `<h:inputText>`s for username and password:

```xml
<form method="POST" action="j_spring_security_check">
...

<h:inputText id="j_username" />

<h:inputSecret id="j_password" />


<h:commandButton name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>

</form>
```

Comment: Ok nice shot, sorry for name/error mistake...i have already changed it. But it works with form method without jsf tag h:  but you need to pass from developement stage to production in web.xml if you don't want to have warnings "The button/link/text component needs to have a Form in its ancestry. Please add <h:form>" but it's ok for me. Great